# iOS UI Test Project 'MailCore/MailCore.h' file not found

Tags: mailcore2

I did a

git clone https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2.git

I open the

iOS UI Test.xcodeproj

I run the Build

I get the error

'MailCore/MailCore.h' file not found

I cannot understand why that is happening.

```
What should I do to get this to build?
```

Some other sources I have found and followed their instructions are below. None of which fixed this problem.

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/316

https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore/issues/19

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/276

I also was able to open the

mailcore2.xcodeproj

and successfully build each of the targets. Which is interesting that I can do that but cannot build the test project independently.

I also followed the video and read me instructions to add to an existing project and was able to build until I added the

```
#import <MailCore/MailCore.h>
```

to one of my files.

UPDATE:

The above process I initiated on my iMac.

On my MacBook Pro after I cloned mailcore2 I opened

mailcore2.xcodeproj

first then did the build on each of the targets.

Then I closed that project.

Opened the iOS UI Test.xcodeproj and did a build on that.

This was successful.

However, I still want to know what would cause the problem with the "file not found"

UPDATE 2:

I removed to trash all mailcore2 code from my iMac.

I created different locations in Finder for doing another clone of mailcore2.

I did the git clone.

I opened mailcore2.xcodeproj

I followed the exact same process of building each target like I did on my MacBook

I then opened the iOS UI Test.xcodeproj and did a build.

I get the same problem of

'MailCore/MailCore.h' file not found

Makes no sense to me how it works on macbook but not on iMac.

Comment: Did you close mailcore2.xcodeproj before trying to compile iOS UI Test.xcodeproj?

Comment: yes i did. thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was drop mailcore2 into an existing app I already had started.

To do this I did the following:

I removed all traces of mailcore2

I again followed the instructions in the README and the video help.

This time I followed some instructions from

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/276

The instructions in that link says to add the following to Library Search Path:

$(PROJECT_DIR)/mailcore2/Externals/ctemplate-ios/lib

$(PROJECT_DIR)/mailcore2/build-mac/build/Debug-iphonesimulator

And the Header Search Path to

$(PROJECT_DIR)/mailcore2/build-mac/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include  - recursively

But, that did not work for me. I had to add the HARD CODED PATH to each of those 3 folders.

After doing a clean and build I was then able to add the

```
#import <MailCore/MailCore.h>
```

Now it BUILDs completely without error for me.

I will go back and try to add proper relative paths to each of those Search Paths.

Hopefully this helps somebody else with same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can add in target dependency static mailcore ios(mailcore2).

and add the framework libmailcore-ios.a

Its working.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW

Had same problem, spend hours trying - nothing worked, not ever hardcoding paths.

Then I stumbled on one issue: 
if in XCode\Preferences\Locations I go to Derived Data - Advanced and set it to different locations it always reverts it to Unique, when I go back and check it.

Then I went in File\Project Setting to Derived Data - Advanced and there it was set to Unique. I changed it there to Default and now it does not have that issue anymore!

I delete Derived data, clean project and Start build (Ctrl+B) and I can see now how Build is being created in derived data w/o problems. And that what mailcore needs to function.

And, I checked - no need for hardcoded paths either!

Hope it helps somebody.
PS Another feature maybe useful too - XCode\Preferences\Continue building after error though it did not matter in my case